# How to take small-sized-(~50KB) good quality screenshots using overlay button?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, screenshots

I'm using [Screenshot Capture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tools.screenshot) to take screenshots using an overlay button (shown in the image).

[image]

The problem with it is that it creates somehow large big size screenshots (around 1MB each). Unfortunately it doesn't provide settings to control the JPG quality of saved screenshots like [Snagit](https://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.html) does (on Windows, shown in image).

[image]

I'm looking for being able to take screenshots using ***hover button***, and also able to control quality settings like *JPG Subfile type and Quality* in order to make screenshots ***smaller*** (~50KB).

---

Note: I know that I can use image converter apps and tools to convert large produced images into smaller. But I'm looking for a direct way to take screenshots directly small (Because often I become away of my laptop, also I don't want to consume time and mind to bother with screenshots size regularly).

My Anrdoid version: 6.0.1

Answer (score 3):

[Touchshot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jbs.util.takescreen) is an app I use which has both you are looking for

- Hover button (overlay)
- `JPEG / PNG` - JPEG quality 80 /90 /100 and resolution can be varied from 640 x 360 , 1280 x 720, 1920 x 1080

Minimum size by manipulating these is still around 100 kB and not as low as you want. There may be other apps that offer size you want but not with overlay function. As an additional feature , you get date and time stamped screenshots

Comment: I think if something provides controlling the **Subfile Type** it can optimize size more. On Snagit changing the **Subfile Type**  to be `YUV 4:4:1` instead of `YUV 4:4:4` dramatically reduces the size, while preserving great quality.

Comment: Maybe , but I am not aware  / knowledgeable about it